# child Progress indicator is not working after collapsed and expanding parent element

Tags: highcharts

start is the parent to test prototype. When I collapsed the Start prototype and expand the progress indicator for the test prototype not showing correctly in the highchart Gantt chart.

https://jsfiddle.net/bhagatch/nbchvupr/2/

```
series: [{
    name: 'Project 1',
    data: [{
        id: 'start',
        name: 'Start prototype',
        start: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 18),
        end: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 25),
        completed: 0.25
    }, {
        id: 'test',
        parent: 'start',
        name: 'Test prototype',
        start: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 27),
        end: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 29),
        completed: 0.35
    }, {
        name: 'Develop',
        start: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 20),
        end: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 25),
        completed: {
            amount: 0.12,
            fill: '#fa0'
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Run acceptance tests',
        start: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 23),
        end: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 26)
    }]
}]
```

});

Comment: What do you mean saying "indicator is not working"? Could you be more precise?

Comment: @WojciechChmiel - Thanks for checking.  When I collapse and expand the parent node(Start prototype) child node (Test prototype) progress indicator is showing only in one color. you can check it in the jsfiddle. but it supposed to show in two different colors as 35% in one color and 65% in a different color. check the https://jsfiddle.net/bhagatch/nbchvupr/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a bug in Highcharts Gantt, reported here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/10942

As a workaround, you can use below code:

```
Highcharts.addEvent(Highcharts.Axis, 'afterBreaks', function() {
    this.series.forEach(s => s.data.forEach(point => point.graphicOverlay = point.graphicOverlay && point.graphicOverlay.destroy()));
});
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/o35pvhfn/